# Big O for 3 nested for loops?

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

```
public int Loop(int[] array1) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 1; k < array1.length; k = k * 2) {
                    result += j * j * array1[k] + array1[i] + array1[j];
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I'm trying to find the complexity function that counts the number of arithmetic operations here. I know the complexity class would be O(n^3), but I'm having a bit of trouble counting the steps.

My reasoning so far is that I count the number of arithmetic operations which is 8, so would the complexity function just be 8n^3?

Any guidance in the right direction would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the complexity is `O(n^3)`? I mean, sure, it would be in `O(n^3)`, in the same way it's in `O(n!)`, but that's not the tightest bound.

Comment: Hm I mean the way we were taught in class was to count the number of steps (arithmetic operations) and then count how many times each operation needs to be done, so that's how I came up with O(n^3). I definitely may be wrong though. I also followed the logic that 2 nested for loops have usually been O(n^2) from what i've done so far.

Comment: Think carefully about the `k = k * 2` in the innermost `ForUpdate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first loop will run `n` times, the second loop will run `n` times however the third loop will run `log(n)` times (base 2). Since you are multiplying `k` by two each time the inverse operation would be to take the log. Multiplying we have `O(n^2 log(n))`

Comment: Ah okay! this makes sense for the complexity class. For counting the exact operations then the function just be f(n) = 8n^2 log(n) right?

Answer (score 2):

If we can agree that the following is one big step:
`result += j * j * array1[k] + array1[i] + array1[j]`
then let's call that **incrementResult**.

How many times is **incrementResult** called here? *(log n)*

```
for (int k = 1; k < array1.length; k = k * 2) {
  // incrementResult 
}
```

Lets call that **loop3**. Then how many times is **loop3** called here? *(n)*

```
for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
  // loop 3
}
```

Let's call that **loop2**. Then, how many times is **loop2** called here? *(n)*

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  // loop 2
}
```

Multiply all of those and you'll get your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the loops. For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            sum += i * j * k;
        }
    }
}
```

has complexity O(1), because the number of iterations does not depend on the input at all.

Or this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n*n*n*n*n*n; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

is O(n^6), even though there is a single loop.

What really matters is how many iterations each loop makes.

In your case, it is easy to see that each iteration of the innermost loop is O(1). How many iterations are there? How many times do you need to double a number until you reach n? If x is the number of iterations, we'd exit the loop at the first x such that k = 2^x > n. Can you solve this for x?

Each iteration of the second loop will do this, so the cost of the second loop is the number of iterations (which are easier to count this time) times the cost of the inner loop.

And each iteration of the first loop will do this, so the cost of the first loop is the number of iterations (which is also easy to count) times the cost of the second loop.

Overall, the runtime is the product of 3 numbers. Can you find them?